# ¿Como recuperar un registro en específico dependiendo de su id en Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web

Necesito recuperar varios datos del Realtime de firebase, e intentado de varias maneras pero no he logrado nada me recupera solo el primer valor y me lo muestra en todo lado, busco es un sistema de publicaciones algo similar como mercado libre
[image: Asi recupero los datos de la base de datos]

[image: Cuando hago click muestro la info de mi producto seleccionado]

[image: Pero al dar click al elemento siguiente me recupera la información del primer elemento y así sucesivamente]

Comment: Que bonito se ve, me encanta si tu pagina aún no esta lista me gustaria que dejaras un comentario en tu pregunta cuando lo este hacia la pagina, asi la podre visitar algún día, eres bueno justo en lo que yo soy malo, el diseño :c

Comment: Ummm tambien decir amigo que deberás dar un paseo por el [tour] y leer sobre [ask], resulta y pasa que según lineamientos de la comunidad tu pregunta no es valida, ya que no contiene un ejemplo minimo y verificable (código) que podamos reproducir, o en caso de no poder reproducirlo simplemente no contiene un código, codigo el cual podremos estudiar para ayudarte en lo que necesitas, considera editar la pregunta y poner el codigo de por ejemplo como intentas recuperar esos datos de firebase y que datos deseas recuperar, omite porfavor o censura en el codigo (xxx-xxx-xxx) informacion sensible.